# Marketo REST API: Form objects?

Tags: marketo

Is it possible to get a list of Form objects via the API yet?
I can't seem to find anything promising in the developer docs, but was hoping it would be in the Asset or Program Object APIs.

I would like to be able to pull a list of available forms into my website CMS via a custom plugin, so I can get the IDs of the forms to easily embed them into the CMS templates.

Comment: The forms API isn't in release yet.  It's planned for the Q2 release.

Comment: Ahah, good to know, thanks @kelkington!